# Any regular expression to extract property from String?

Tags: java, regex

I have a String which contains a set of properties like the following one:

```
"T=Junior Developer, DNQ=13346057, SURNAME=Doe, GIVENNAME=John, SERIALNUMBER=UK"
```

Is there a Regular Expression which can be used in Java to gather the individual properties (such as the SURNAME) ? 
Thanks

Comment: This looks like CSV. What is the source?

Comment: It is important to remember that regular expressions are used to get/match a charecter sequence inside a string. So it is very important to know the format of the Surname. SURNAME=[^,]+ can be a good solution, but doesn't work if a surname can contain a comma character... so you have to exactly define the format of the all possible surnames before trying to match it by a regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SURNAME=[^,]+
```

You can use this.Or to be safer you can also use

```
SURNAME=.*?(?=,\s)
```

The second one will work even if you have `,` in your surname.

Answer (score 3):

This small example shows how to access the property name and its value in your example string. This is for all properties and values in the string.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "T=Junior Developer, DNQ=13346057, SURNAME=Doe, GIVENNAME=John, SERIALNUMBER=UK";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?:, )?([^=]+)\\=([^,]+)").matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
      System.out.println(m.group(1) + " - " + m.group(2));
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
(?:, )?([^=]+)\\=([^,]+)
```

- `(?:, )?` is a non-capturing group that can, but does not have to occur. It matches the seperation by the comma and space between the property-value pairs.
- `([^=]+)` is a group that matches one or more characters until a `=` appears.
- `\\=` matches the `=`. It is a special character and thus has to be escaped.
- `([^,]+)` matches one or more characters up to the next `,`, when the next propery will start.

Comment: Thanks! also your example worked. I've chosen anyway the first reply, just on a time basis